# Spring JPA One2Many Relationship ids are not updated/inserted correctly

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, postgresql, jpa

I'm working on a Spring/React project where I have about 10 tables, which hold several relations.

But I got a really annoying situation where I just can't find the right solution. I have a few tables which hold one2many relations:

```
Product.category_id --> Category.id
Product.manufacturer_id --> Manufacturer.id
```

Product entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
private Category category;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Manufacturer manufacturer;
```

Product Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/admin/product")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
    System.out.println(product.getCategory());
    System.out.println(product.getManufacturer());
    productRepository.save(product);
    URI location;
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Toegevoegd", HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

 @PutMapping(value = "/admin/product/{id}")
    public Product updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable Long id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id)
            .map(updateProduct -> {
                updateProduct.setCategory(product.getCategory());
                updateProduct.setManufacturer(product.getManufacturer());
                updateProduct.setName(product.getName());
                updateProduct.setPrice(product.getPrice());
                updateProduct.setTaste(product.getTaste());
                updateProduct.setImagePath(product.getImagePath());
                updateProduct.setStock(product.getStock());
                updateProduct.setDescription(product.getDescription());
                updateProduct.setType(product.getType());
                return productRepository.save(updateProduct);
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                return productRepository.save(product);
            });
    }
```

Category entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Product> Product;
```

The relation works when i get the overview of products, i get "1 - test", but when I want to send a POST request, both manufacturer/category's are always null. The output I send with Postman:

```
{

    "categoryId": "999",
    "name":"Test",
    "taste":"sdads",
    "price":"1",
    "stock": "123",
    "manufacturerId": "1",
    "description" : "213",
    "discount" : "0"
}
```

Because of the camelCase convention it has to be sent this way from the front-end. The annoying part is that, when I didn't add a relation between product-category / product-manufacturer and I used:

```
@Column(name="manufacturer_id")
private long manufacturerId;

@Column(name="category_id")
private long categoryId;
```

It did work, I could Post/Put data and it was saved to the database. When I use this code along with the one2many mapping, it says 'category' was already defined (or smt). A teacher said the framework would automatically manage it and said the relationships were ok. Well, its not working.

What is the correct way of saving data WITH a relationship? All the other non-relation columns have no issues updating/inserting.

Comment: Can you post here the error or the stacktrace generated by the application when you use `@ManyToOne`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when you send POST query with your JSON, Jackson converts that JSON to Product object. And since Product has not fields like manufacturerId or categoryId, Jackson ignores them.

And no wonder category and manufacturer fields are null - JSON has no such fields.

You should make a class ProductDto with same fields as Product except for it should have manufacturerId and categoryId instead of manufacturer and. And you should convert ProductDto to Product manually in your code, filling category with categoryId and manufacturer with manufacturerId. This is the right way.

Another option is to add full Manufacturer and Categoty object to your JSON

```json
{
    "category": {
        "id": "999"
     },
    "name":"Test",
    "taste":"sdads",
    "price":"1",
    "stock": "123",
    "manufacturer": {
        "id": "1"
    },
    "description" : "213",
    "discount" : "0"
}

Should work, but I don't recomend it
```

Comment: The second option you give works (with id, not categoryid). But you would not recommend it, can you give me a reason why? At the lessons DTO is not really mentioned, so that is new, I'm curious. Because of possible empty data in both those objects?

Comment: It is not recommended, because in general case, you should not make you Enities known to the outer world. Suppose , you will decide, that you should not map OneToMany, but just map manufacturerId column because of performance. You will have to tell people to restructure their queries. But if you have DTO in you controller, you only have to change your merhod's code.